# Elastic Search/Tire: How do I filter a boolean attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I want to filter the private boolean of my class so it only shows resources that aren't private but it's not working for me. (I dumbed down the code tremendously)

```
mapping do
  indexes :private,  type: "boolean"
  indexes :name, type: "string"
 end 
end

def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
       query  { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
       # So far I've tried...
       # filter :bool, :private => ["false"] 
       # filter :bool,  private: false
    end
end
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
  filter :term, :private => false
```

Should do the trick. Depending on whether you want to do stuff with facets it may be more efficient to do your filtering a filtered query rather than at the top level, ie

```
tire.search(...) do 
  query do
    filtered do
      query { string, params[:query] }
      filter :term, :private => false
    end
  end
end
```

It shouldn't change the results though.

You can also do this with a `bool` filter, but not quite how you tried - within a bool filter you need to build up a [structure](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter.html) that says what's optional and what's not

For example

```
tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
   query  { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present
   filter :bool, :must => {:term => {:private => true}}
end
```

A `bool` filter is slower than using an `and` filter (which is what tire does behind the scenes if you specify multiple filters) but obviously gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
    query do
        boolean do
            must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
            must { term :private, true }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [elasticsearch - guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types.html), booleans are stored as T or F, so I would try filtering by T or F.

For example

```
filter :terms, :private => ['T']
```

I haven't actually used tires, this is just based on some research on the guide and in the [examples](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/examples/tire-dsl.rb).